# HTML Table th cell does not respond to a percentage width, but does respond to a pixel width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap for my CSS on a project I'm working on. 
[image]

as you can see in the image I've added, the width of my th cell is larger than the actual text I've added in it (which my bootstrap css automatically truncates). I want the red lines to start at the same point my blue line does. But this is being blocked from doing so because of the size of my th cell.

the code for my table is included below:

```html
<table class="table bg-light table-sm table-responsive" style="width: 100%">
    <tbody style="width:100%">
    <tr style="width:100%">
        <th scope="row" style="width:5%">
            <div class="text-truncate" style="width: 100%">10.1</div>
        </th>

        <td>
            <div style="width: 95%">
            //...
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    
    
    <tr style="width:100%">
        <th scope="row" style="width:5%">
            <div class="text-truncate" style="width: 100%">UNKNOWN</div>
        </th>

        <td>
            <div style="width: 95%">
            //...
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I change the widths in the div/th cells and all parent tags to a pixel value instead of a percentage, the table does what I want (reduce the th cells size so that the red bars can start where the blue bar starts, text inside the cell becomes truncated) but when it is percentage values, the th cells stay as wide as the largest text in the column (in this case where it says "UNKNOWN").

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that HTML table will occupy the space it needs to display **all** the content inside it (it won't truncate it). So, if the table content asks for 2000px the table will respect it. Therefor, your cell width presented in percents will respect the table width. The only way you can really control the table cell width is to change the table layout:

```
 table-layout: fixed;
```

But please note, it won't behave as a table it used to be. More about fixed table layouts [here](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/).